# What year is specialized stumpjumper sold? What rear shock does it have?

Tags: shocks

My rear shocks is leaking. I took it to the store and they do not fix it.

What model is it? Year?
And what FOX shock is it?

Does it worth to fix it? Or shall I buy something else?

Riding level: entry/medium
Thank you for your help

[image]

Comment: That is a loverly bike - could you take a couple clear and well-lit photos of the brain itself, then [edit] them into the question?

Answer (score 9):

You don't have a Stumpjumper, you have a 2002 Epic FSR and the shock built specially for Specialized features 'Brain' technology.  This is quite a special bike since we see the introduction of the inertia valve in suspension.

Here is a nice article from when your bike was launched: https://www.pinkbike.com/news/article819.html

And another article giving a more complete up to date history of the Epic:  https://www.velonews.com/gear/the-evolution-of-the-epic/

Comment: *Recommended service intervals increased to 125 hours for the air spring (a 2.5X increase), and to 250 for the new one* ... who knows what were the intervals for the 2002. Probably "service after every ride"

Answer (score 5):

When I have been confronted with older Specialized Brain components before, I have followed the trail up by speaking to Specialized warranty department to see who does the warranty service in your country. For me, it is a company in Bedfordshire who also service Fox and Rockshox. As it is a Fox part, there is a good likelihood that a service centre will have common service parts even for older shocks but sometimes unique internal components are unavailable. Even so, it’s worth sending the shock to a specialist. I’m surprised your shop wouldn’t arrange this for you.

Comment: In my experience most shops want nothing to do with the suspension components - not ideal for the end customer when there's only a few places in the country that do the job and it means removing the part themselves.

Comment: The specialised "brain" is not normal suspension parts, it uses the weirdest system of levers and gas and weighted masses to react fast to inputs.  It literally is an analogue computer working off gas pressures.   https://www.specialized.com/nz/en/stories/brain-technology shows a cutaway of the brain.   Definitely cool though the unskilled tech would have problems with servicing it.

Comment: @Criggie but the service parts, seals, o-rings etc and required tooling is all fox. No unique parts are available for anything over 10 years old but they can still be serviced.